# Copy the terminal session to a file

Tags: macos, unix

Is there any way to copy the output printed in the terminal to a file.In my case the commands 'script' , 'tee' and '>>' wont work because i already executed  my program and given a large output which am not able to copy from the terminal

Comment: This belongs on superuser, but anyway: *Which* terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. 
There is an option in terminal->shell-> Export text As. Which resolved my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't intercept a running program's existing filehandles and transparently redirect them elsewhere.  Some terminal emulators may support logging; if your terminal has enough scrollback you could copy and paste it (although be careful where you paste it to, if it's voluminous; feeding it to other terminals may result in much of it being lost when the pty buffer fills).